# How do I prevent my phone from waking up when I slide out the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I have a Motorola Droid 4 which has a slide-out keyboard.  The problem is, the sliding action takes very little force, and if the phone is in my pocket, just simply walking can cause the slider to open just a tiny bit.

This is a Very Bad Thing for two reasons.  First, the battery drains far faster than it should because the screen is frequently turning on.  Second, my leg often activates the Emergency Dialer on the lock screen and starts pressing buttons.  I'm worried I'm going to pocket-dial 911 some day.

So is there a way to disable waking up when the keyboard opens?